# How to delete a document in firestore by fetching its autogenerated id?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to delete a document or a sub-document in Firestore & how to fetch its auto-generated id so that when the user long presses, selects 'delete' on a row item in the list so that he/she can delete a document from the user interface of the app easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "fetch" an existing random document.  In order to delete a document you need to do either one of two things:

- Remember the generated ID on the client, and use that to build a DocumetnReference to delete the document
- Query for the document using a field that you know in that document, then delete it after the query.  Or simply query for all documents and work with them as a group.

If you can't query for a document using its fields, and you don't know it's ID, you're kind of stuck, and you will need to think more carefully about your data model.

Comment: well, you have explained the scenario quite well, but how to track the ID ? I am kind of  stuck now. How can one design model class to eliminate this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to delete a document or a sub-document in Firestore

To delete document you have to use `delete()` method

**Kotlin Code**:

```
db.collection("your_collection_name").document("documentId")
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!") }
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e) }
```

You need to know your `collection name` and `documentId` you want to delete. Use your `collection name` and `documentId` to delete a document from a collection.

Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents) for more

> how to fetch its auto-generated id

To read all document in a collection you also need to know `collection name`.

**To read documents in a collection in Kotlin:**

```
db.collection("your_collection_name")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
```

`document.id` will give you every `documentId`. Use this `documentId` to delete a document.

To read all documents from a collection check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)

Comment: how to get one specific document ID that was randomly generated ?