# How to delete Item from firestore in android with auto-generated document ID

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database with the following structure in a hierarchical form:

**collection("notes") > document(currentUserId) > collection("mynotes") > document(auto-generated-key) > items...**

I have added data to the Firestore as follows :

```
   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
  
   //here scheduleModel is a model class with constructor(String, boolean, String) with getters and 
   //setters for three of them 
   scheduleNoteModel = new ScheduleNote(noteTitle, isImp, strDate);
```

I have added the note item like this.

```
database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid())
            .collection("mynotes")
            .document() //generated id automatically...
            .set(scheduleNoteModel)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "data added ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    etNoteTitle.setText("");
                    //dismiss (hide) the bottom sheet after adding item
                    BottomSheetScheduleFragment.this.dismiss();

                    //refresh the fragment
                }
            });
```

The problem is getting that id back while deleting the item. I know there are many questions similar to this, some of them were good but I couldn't figure out to solve them. I had a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361039/deleting-a-document-from-firestore-via-auto-generated-document-id) solution but I wasn't able to solve

In adapter

```
 holder.deleteNoteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteNote(noteModel);
        }
    });


Method to delete

    private void deleteNote(ScheduleNote note, int itemPosition, View view) {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //getting the doc id of auto-generated code in Firestore.
     String id = database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("mynotes").document().getId();

    Toast.makeText(context, "position " + itemPosition + "doc id " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid())
            .collection("mynotes")
            //.document("72NMkKY73CXHVN7DFE8W") get that id automatically
            .document(id)
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    //notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Note Deleted successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            });
}
```

id in the above variable isn't matching the real id. How to get that id?

I basically want two information for this :

1. How to get the document Id before adding it to the Firestore so that I can attach this to my model class and later on delete based on that ID, has any solution?
2. Or, just get the document Id by the Model Class that I pass when clicking on the item in RecyclerView?

I actually did a lot of research but couldn't figure it out. Any quick help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Calling `document().getId()` just generates a new unique ID, so that document won't exist. Instead of focusing on what you don't know (the ID), what **do** you know of the document you want to delete. Say there are 100 documents in the collection, how do you decide which one(s) you want to delete? Once you know that, you can probably write a query to delete those documents as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180442. Also see Doug's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63972796

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just want to get that Id, that's my main point.

Comment: You might want to store the document ID in the Notes class when you fetch the data from db or add a new task.

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes, but I am not able to find the doc ID prior to adding my note. That's the problem. Any help would be great if you know. Not too complex but I haven't found the solutions.

Comment: You can actually add the data in firestore first which will then have a response containing the document key in the success listener. Then after adding to successfully, construct the object using scheduledNote class.

Comment: Please add your code where you add data to firesotre and also the notes class

Comment: @Dharmaraj well,  success listener has void on onSuccess() which has no method. And also , I mentioned that my model class with three attributes with constructor(String, boolean, String) with getters and setters for three of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to mee, that you are following this [link solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361039/deleting-a-document-from-firestore-via-auto-generated-document-id). First of all, as also @Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment, "document().getId()" will always generate a brand new ID each time is called. So you should save that ID into a variable for later use, so you can delete the desired document right from the adapter. Your "ScheduleNote" class, besides the "noteTitle", "isImp", and "strDate" fields, should also contain a field called "id". So your declaration class should look like this:

```
class ScheduleNote {
    public String noteTitle, strDate, id;
    public boolean isImp;

    public ScheduleNote() {}

    public ScheduleNote(String noteTitle, String strDate, String id, boolean isImp) {
        this.noteTitle = noteTitle;
        this.strDate = strDate;
        this.id = id;
        this.isImp = isImp;
    }
}
```

Now, in your particular case, the following lines of code for adding the object to Firestore will do the trick:

```
CollectionRefference mynotes = database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid())
        .collection("mynotes")
String docId = mynotes.document().getId();
```

To create an object of "ScheduleNote" type, please use:

```
ScheduleNote scheduleNoteModel = new ScheduleNote(noteTitle, strDate, docId, isImp);
//                                                                     ^
//                                                                newly added
```

To actually write the data to Firestore, please use:

```
mynotes.document(docId).set(scheduleNoteModel).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
//                 ^
```

To be able to delete that document, you should use the following lines of code:

```
database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid())
        .collection("mynotes")
        .document(id)
        .delete(note.id)
        .addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
```

And this is because, the following line generates **again** a new ID, which is not correct, as you need to use the one that was generated earlier:

```
String id = database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("mynotes").document().getId();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solves and also the explanation is clear . Actually I was confused with the CollectionReference you mentioned in that explanation. Also, this line of code that I wrote String id = database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("mynotes").document().getId();
If I used this id as the id field in model class, and make document ID as well while adding my note,this also works. Is that solution is same as the one you have written ? I think if id is unique every time I add note to database, it is fine.

Comment: Yes, that exact same solution but is rewritten for your exact use-case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add document to your collection without any data in it.

```
DocumentReference addedDocRef =database.collection("notes").document(mAuth.getUid())
            .collection("mynotes")
            .document();
log.i("Added document with ID: " + addedDocRef.getId());
```

Then add document id to your model class for later use.

Now, set data for document using your model class.

```
addedDocRef.set(scheduleNoteModel)
```